# Ajax shopping cart doesn't show items

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make one very simple ajax shopping cart. So far I have the cart and based on the ajax function I see that when I click on `Add to Cart` button the number of items in cart increased.

The problem now is with show the cart button. When I tried to slide cart it doesn't slide. I think that the problem is in PHP part but where I loop in database to take all the ID's and show the result.. At least that function doesn't work and that's why I think the problem is there.

This is the PHP part:

```
// counting items in cart and showing on the page - work
if(isset($_POST['total_cart_items']))
{
   echo count($_SESSION['itemid']);
   exit();
}

// post item into cart - work
if(isset($_POST['item_id']))
{

    $_SESSION['itemid'][]=$_POST['item_id'];
    echo count($_SESSION['itemid']);
    exit();
}

// this part is the problem as doesn't show the cart
if(isset($_POST['showcart']))
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['itemid']);$i++)
    {

        $sql = "SELECT upload_lesson_plan, upload_worksheet, upload_materials FROM document_upload where upload_id = ?"; 
        $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute(array($_SESSION['itemid']));                 

        foreach ( $result as $row ){

            echo '<div class="cart_items" style="text-align:center;">
                    <a href=""><p>'.$row["itemid"][$i].'</p></a>
                  </div>';
        }
    }
    exit(); 
}
```

This is the ajax/js part

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'includes/store_items.php',
    data:{
      total_cart_items:"totalitems"
    },
    success:function(response) {
      document.getElementById("total_items").value=response;
    }
  });

});

function cart(itemid)
{
    var ele=document.getElementById(itemid);    
    $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'includes/store_items.php',
    data:{
      item_id:itemid        
    },
    success:function(response) {
      document.getElementById("total_items").value=response;
    }
  });

}

function show_cart()
{
  $.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:'includes/store_items.php',
  data:{
    showcart:"cart"
  },
  success:function(response) {
    document.getElementById("mycart").innerHTML=response;
    $("#mycart").slideToggle();
  }
 });
}
```

Last function `function show_cart()` is the problem. Also if need here is the HTML but this also work.

```
<p id="cart_button" style="text-align:center;" onclick="show_cart();">
    <img src="img/cart_icon.png">
    <input type="button" id="total_items" value="">
</p>

<div id="mycart" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

UPDATE:

```
    for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['itemid']);$i++)
    {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM document_upload where upload_id = ?"; 
        $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute(array($_SESSION['itemid'])); 
        foreach ( $result as $row ):?>
          <div class="cart_items" style="text-align:center;">
               <a href=""><p><?=$row["itemid"][$i]?></p></a>
          </div>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
    }
```

Comment: Not a user of PDO, but don't you need to fetch the results. i.e `$result->fetch()` before the `foreach` loop?

Comment: Still same. Cart just doesn't open..

Comment: Make sure you started session;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7, at the top of the page I've including database config where I start also the session. Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result` is and **object** containing the query, parameters... that you use to prepare query, bind parameters, execute... But he **does not** contain the result...

You have differents ways to get the result:

```
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //load ONE row as array(colName => colValue)... First call: returns the first row. Second call, the second one... When there is no more rows, returns FALSE
$rows = $result->fetchAll(); //the one we use: a big array with all rows returned . We 'll do like this one...
```

Also, I have a better way to set request parameters (better for me because by this way you name your params):

```
$result->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

You need to do:

```
<?php
//...
// counting items in cart and showing on the page - work
if(isset($_POST['total_cart_items']))
{
   echo count($_SESSION['itemid']);
   exit();
}

// post item into cart - work
if(isset($_POST['item_id']))
{    
    $_SESSION['itemid'][]=$_POST['item_id'];
    echo count($_SESSION['itemid']);
    exit();
}

// this part is the problem as doesn't show the cart
if(! isset($_POST['showcart'])) exit; //problem
foreach ($_SESSION['itemid'] as $i):

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM document_upload where upload_id = :id"; 
        $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $result->bindParam(":id", $i, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->execute();                 


        $resArray = $result->fetchAll(); //return the array of results

         foreach ( $resArray as $row ):?>
             <div class="cart_items" style="text-align:center;">
                  <a href=""><p><?=$row["upload_title"]?> - <?=$row["upload_description"]?></p></a>
             </div>
        <?php endforeach;
 endforeach; ?>
```

Better because with this structure,  you manipulate directly HTML...

But from SQL part: you want to only select some items? don't use a "for" loop like that! Use a request like:

```
SELECT * FROM document_upload where upload_id IN (id1, id2, id3)...
```

No more for, better performances...

Comment: Thank's but I've got `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in ` and can't se why

Comment: check if you have an unclosed PHP tag / a missing semicolon , or other things ?

Comment: You need also to have short open tags enabled in order to use `<?=$var?>` alias... but it is enabled by default

Comment: One question: Why is this and don't I need one `{` because it throws error `unexpected }` -> `if(!isset($_POST['item_id'])) exit; //problem` What is the problem?

Comment: I saw why is `exit;` .. because on each click on cart it adds `+1`

Comment: I just replace `if... then for....` etc. By a if not then exit: cleaner for me (if we have not `$_POST['showcar']`, then we stop here)

Comment: And what does your table looks like? and what parameter do you want to display? Because the current `<?= $row['itemid'][$i]` is not correct...

Comment: Something isn't right. Now if I have in cart `1` item and I click on the cart to see this item it increment it with `+1` and I see `id=2` if I click on cart again I see `id=3` and so on

Comment: I want to show some rows from the table.. for example `upload_title`, `upload_description`..

Comment: and for rows, as you can see in my example, just do `$row['COL_NAME']` to retrieve the content

Comment: I saw but now I got error here `<a href=""><p><?=$row["upload_title"]?> - <?=row["upload_title"]?></p></a>` and the error is `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' `

Comment: yep ! `<?=$row`, not `<?=row` ... don't miss the dollar!

Comment: Yes, I saw it and just replace it but still same error on same line. Also I don't see numbers of total items in cart this is first `if`..`if(isset($_POST['total_cart_items']))`

Comment: It should be... And do you have short open tags enabled in your php conf? If not, or if you are not sure, just replace `<?=$var?>` by `<?php echo $var; ?>`...

Comment: I'm not sure. And let me tell what is happen now. On cart there is `0` for zero items. When I click on add to cart i don't see `1` or other number .. doesn't see `0` also. And when I click on cart I see this `?>`

Comment: Doesn't save anything in cart and when I click on cart finally it is opened but I see only - `?>`

Comment: Now it is saving in the cart normally .. just still when I click on cart it open and show this `?>`. I've tried and replaced short tags and still same `<a href=""><p><?php echo $row["upload_title"]; ?> - <?php echo $row["upload_description"]; ?></p></a>`

Comment: Even when I put something static there like: `<a href=""><p>Just testing</p></a>` again show same `?>`

Comment: Very very strange... Do you have something else in your file? because when I test I don"t have errors...

Comment: In this file no, i don't

Comment: So, where do you initialize your SQL connection?

Comment: It is in another file. I use datatable and made custom button on the last column. `item_id` is the ID of the item in database.. `<a onclick="cart(\'item' + full[0] + '\')" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href=javascript:;>' + 'Add to Cart' + '</a>'`

Comment: And where do you include it? (the connection file)

Comment: Try this file (no SQL connexion, just a test to test the whole syntax) : http://pastebin.com/kVP2wcnq

Comment: I'm including it at the top right after `<?php` -> `include ../../misc/database.inc.php'; $pdo = Database::connect();`

Comment: `include .'./../misc/database.inc.php'` I hope! because `include ../../misc/database.inc.php'`...

Comment: This source from the pastebin is working and the cart is showing me `title 1-5`, `title 1-6` ...

Comment: OK, so the problem does not come from file... in your php.ini, set error_reporting to E_ALL, and show us what is the error (with DB connexion ? not the good columns?

Comment: Well I can't believe what was the problem. This `?>` actually is the last `?>` after ` endforeach; ?>`..

Comment: Last question: how to restrict one item to be added in cart just one time.

Comment: Because in my file I don't see... I've just tested with a DB , it perfectly work

Comment: It is working perfectly now. The problem was with the `?>` which close starting `<?php` which is at the top of the file. Now is working. Just wondering how to check if this itemid is already in cart and if is don't save it again

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5gSeewwi : your answer; and this one works for me... try (make sure to change connection params, table name, etc...)

Comment: The last `?>` isn't necessary if you don't have anything after it, just remove it so... And so if your problem is solved, you can mark this answer as "accepted", to mark the question as answered ;)

Comment: i don't understand.. I logged out from the account then log in again and .. doesn't open the cart again. I will continue to try and figured out what is the problem. At least it's huge progress for me and thank's!

Comment: What are this `cols`? `<a href=""><p><?=$row["col41"]?> - <?=$row["col2"]?></p></a>`

Comment: maybe check your $_SESSION, and your $_POST content (by a `print_r` or `var_dump`).  and theses cols was just examples (I randomly shoot on my keyboard ;)), and they are the table's column names

Comment: When I open cart and `print_r($_SESSION)` -> `Array ( [0] => item1 [1] => item1 [2] => item14 [3] => item1 [4] => item1 [5] => item20 [6] => item19 [7] => item18 [8] => item17 [9] => item16 [10] => item14 [11] => item12 )` which is correct info. But again cart doesn't show .. :)

Comment: `print_r($i)` also return correct info but inside foreach when I `print_r($row)` cart doesn't open.

Comment: what you mean with `And what about $_POST (is $_POST['showcart'] set?) `?

Comment: Can you print_r `$_POST` (because on your code, if $_POST['showcart'] isn't set, the cart won't load), so let us see what' inside it

Comment: I've put `print_r($_POST)` right after `if(! isset($_POST['showcart'])) exit; //problem` and in cart when I open I see `Array ( [showcart] => cart )`

Comment: Change `PDO::PARAM_INT` to `PDO::PARAM_STR` (your IDs seems to be strings)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109256/discussion-between-jordan-vit-and-vincent).

Comment: Something strange that I noticed just now. I've removed whole source and paste this from pastebin.com/kVP2wcnq and when I put back my source I've got different number of items in cart and is worked. Then I logged out and logged in again and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

Problem is in the way you are using to pass id to the query:

```
$itemsInCart = count($_SESSION['itemid']);
for($i = 0; $i < $itemsInCart; $i++){
    $sql = "SELECT upload_lesson_plan, upload_worksheet, upload_materials FROM document_upload where upload_id = ?"; 
    $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    /* you forgot to get current item from array using index $i */
    $result->execute(array($_SESSION['itemid'][$i]));       

    /* fetch all records */
    $records = $result->fetchAll();
    foreach ( $records as $row ){
        /* one more thing you have not selected itemid column in query so you can't get it right now you passed 3 columns;  */
        echo '<div class="cart_items" style="text-align:center;">
                <a href=""><p>' . $row["upload_lesson_plan"] . '</p></a>
              </div>';
    }
}
```

With foreach loop:

```
foreach($_SESSION['itemid'] as $currentItemId){
    $sql = "SELECT upload_lesson_plan, upload_worksheet, upload_materials FROM document_upload where upload_id = ?"; 
    $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    /* you forgot to get current item from array using index $i */
    $result->execute(array($currentItemId));       

    /* fetch all records */
    $records = $result->fetchAll();
    foreach ( $records as $row ){
        /* one more thing you have not selected itemid column in query so you can't get it right now you passed 3 columns;  */
        echo '<div class="cart_items" style="text-align:center;">
                <a href=""><p>' . $row["upload_lesson_plan"] . '</p></a>
              </div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's. I've tried your solution also but still cart doesn't open.

Comment: Can you share the live web link where we can test it ourselves to see the flow;

Comment: I don't have it live yet..:(

Comment: I must replace inside last `IF` in my code with this whole portion of code, right? Just inside..

Comment: Yes any of the code block with `for` or with `foreach`;

Comment: Then try adding this `print_r($_SESSION);` before the `if` condition; and share what you get;